# Arabic font is not supported when using csv format in maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel, csv, xls, maatwebsite-excel

I export excel files using maatwebsite/excel package, everything is fine when I use xls format and the arabic letters shows correctly, but when trying to use csv format the arabic text doesn't show, can anyone hint me how it could be fixed?

Comment: Try opening the exported CSV with a text editor like Atom or Sublime and see if it shows correctly

Comment: Are you exporting in `UTF-8` format?

Comment: @Danny_ds yes I'm, the format has no problem when I export in xls , but only csv

Comment: @teeyo I tried and it shows correctly with a text editor, what might be the problem then

Answer (score 2):

Try by modifying file:

```
vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\config\excel.php
```

in line 145 :

```
'use_bom' => true
```